# passing user input (EditText) between activities, and then using that in formula

Tags: java, android, string

I want from user to input his name in one `EditText` widget, then to input his weight in other `EditText` widget, and after that to proceed that data from one activity to another one.

Weight input should later be included in one formula, and name input should be settled in `TextView` widget with result of the formula.

But, when i start my app, at the end Android Studio shows me `NullPointerException`. I suppose that err is somewhere in data sharing between activities.
So, here is the code. If you can, pls help me :)

ActivityOne (name of activity is InformacijeM) XML file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_informacije_m"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.alkometar.InformacijeM"
    android:background="@drawable/activitybackground">

    <TextView
        android:text="Ukucaj svoje ime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/UkucajIme" />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/strelamanja"
        android:id="@+id/strelica"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/ImeInput"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/UkucajIme"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/MasaInput"
        android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/strelica"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Ukucaj svoju masu u kg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/UkucajMasu"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/MasaInput"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ActivityOne (InformacijeM) Java file:

```
    package com.example.alkometar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class InformacijeM extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ImeTxt, MasaTxt ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_informacije_m);

        // INICIRANJE VREDNOSTI


        EditText ImeTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ImeInput);
        final String str1 = ImeTxt.getText().toString();

        EditText MasaTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MasaInput);
        final String str2 = MasaTxt.getText().toString();

        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.strelica);
        // PREBACIVANJE AKTIVITIJA
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(InformacijeM.this, RezultatM.class);
                intent1.putExtra("keyIme", str1);
                intent1.putExtra("keyMasa", str2);

                Intent intent = new Intent(InformacijeM.this, StanjeM.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }}
```

ActivityTwo (Name of activity is RezultatM) XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_rezultat_m"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.alkometar.RezultatM"
    android:background="@drawable/activitybackground">

    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
        android:id="@+id/rezultatTekst" />

    <Button
        android:text="Rezultat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ActivityTwo (RezultatM) Java file:

```
    package com.example.alkometar;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RezultatM extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView rezultat;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rezultat_m);


        rezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultatTekst);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                 {
                    String str1 = extras.getString("keyIme");
                    String str2 = extras.getString("keyMasa");


                double masad = Double.valueOf(str2);
                double nekibroj = 0.8;
                double result = masad * nekibroj;

                rezultat.setText(str1 + "Nivo alkohola u tvojoj krvi je:" + result);
            }
        };
        });
    }}
```

Strings.xml file:

```
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">Alkometar</string>
    <string name="ImeInput">ImeInput</string>
    <string name="MasaInput">MasaInput</string>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alkometar">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Pol">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".InformacijeM" />
        <activity android:name=".StanjeM" />
        <activity android:name=".InformacijeZ" />
        <activity android:name=".StanjeZ" />
        <activity android:name=".PijemM" />
        <activity android:name=".RezultatM"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the exception in logCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.alkometar, PID: 30732
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.example.alkometar.RezultatM$1.onClick(RezultatM.java:28)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you very much once again! :)))

Comment: At which line is the exception thrown? We can easily find the problem if you could tell that.

Comment: I supose that the problem is in passing the strings trough activities... :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Activity Two class to:

```
public class RezultatM extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView rezultat;
String str1,str2;
double masad;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rezultat_m);


    rezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultatTekst);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //str1 = intent.getStringExtra("keyIme");
    //str2 = intent.getStringExtra("keyMasa"); 
    //getting values from shared preferences
     SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    str1=shared.getString("keyIme", "");
    str2=shared.getString("keyMasa", "");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(str2!=null){
            masad = Double.parseDouble(str2);
            }
            double nekibroj = 0.8;
            double result = masad * nekibroj;

            rezultat.setText(str1 + "Nivo alkohola u tvojoj krvi je:" + result);
    };
    });
}}
```

Also in your Activity one you are starting wrong intent

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(InformacijeM.this, RezultatM.class);
 intent1.putExtra("keyIme", str1);
 intent1.putExtra("keyMasa", str2);

 Intent intent = new Intent(InformacijeM.this, StanjeM.class);
// startActivity(intent); //here you are starting another class..check it
//change it to
startActivity(intent1);
```

change your InformacijeM.java class:

```
    public class InformacijeM extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ImeTxt, MasaTxt ;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_informacije_m);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // INICIRANJE VREDNOSTI


        EditText ImeTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ImeInput);
        final String str1 = ImeTxt.getText().toString();

        EditText MasaTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MasaInput);
        final String str2 = MasaTxt.getText().toString();
        save_data(str1,str2);
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.strelica);
        // PREBACIVANJE AKTIVITIJA
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(InformacijeM.this, RezultatM.class);
                intent1.putExtra("keyIme", str1);
                intent1.putExtra("keyMasa", str2);

                Intent intent = new Intent(InformacijeM.this, StanjeM.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    public void save_data(String s1,String s2){
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
         editor.putString("keyIme", s1);
         editor.putString("keyMasa", s2);
         editor.commit();
         }  
}
```

Comment: In ActivityTwo, when i edit this, variable masad in result is red (it said that android studio can't resolve symbol 'masad'). Should i put other two variables (nekibroj and result) together with masad variable ?
And in ActivityOne:
When i click the button, i want from app to go to the second activity wich is called StanjeM, but also, i want that user input data go to the last activity, and with them i want to calculate some formula.
(RezultatM isn't the nect activity after InformacijeM. Next activity is StanjeM).

Comment: I suposse that this will be good, but here is one problem...
(Sorry if the solutions of this is realy stupid, i'm still the beginner :) ):

AS said that him cannot resolve symbol 'sharedPreferences'....

And just one question, i'm in doubt. When i solve this problem with sharedPreferences, should I, in RezultatM.class use str1 and str2 strings, or s1 or s2 ? Did they have the same value ? :)

Best regards! :)

Comment: they have the same value ...in RezultatM.class you can use s1 and s2 to retreive the value

Comment: check the edited RezultatM.class ..if it works...pls do accept the answer

Comment: Now is okay.
But, where exactly to put this Load_data method in RezultatM.class ?

Can you do that ? :)
Sry again. :)
When will everything be okay, i will accept the answer, don't worry ;) :)

Comment: in onCreate() of  RezultatM.class ...try make string s1,s2 global ...so u can use them in other function of RezultatM class

Comment: Whereever i puts Load_data method it shows me next:
1. '}' expected - in line before i put the Load_data method
2. Cannot resolve symbol setOnClickListener
3. Cannot resolve symbol onClick

I suposse that when i initiate Load_data method, the same method I should put in onClick method with: Load_data(); ?

It would be nice if you could write this in code in message above. It would be easier for me, and before all for other programers who have the same problem as i have :)
Best regards! :)

Comment: It shows me exception in RezultatM.class for masad= Double.valueOf(str2); 
It said : "Invalid double: ""

When i input weight, i write 75. Maybe i must input some decimal number???

Comment: use Double.parseDouble instead of  Double.valueOf

Comment: I will accept answer when i finish my problem, don't worry :) 
Still the same: "invalid double "" " for masad ....

Comment: Sooo, do you have some answer ?